# Stream of Strings isn't sorted?

Tags: java, sorting, java-8, java-stream

i would like to find the set of all words in a file.This set should be sorted.
Upper and Lower Case doesn't matter. 
Here is my approach:

```
public static Set<String> setOfWords(String fileName) throws IOException {

    Set<String> wordSet;
    Stream<String> stream = java.nio.file.Files.lines(java.nio.file.Paths.get(fileName));

    wordSet = stream
                .map(line -> line.split("[ .,;?!.:()]"))
                .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
                .sorted()
                .map(String::toLowerCase)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    stream.close();
    return wordSet;
}
```

Test file:

This is a file with 
five lines.It has two sentences, 
and the word file is contained 
in multiple lines of this file. 
This file can be used for testing?

When printing the set, i get the following output:

```
Set of words: 
a
be
in
sentences
testing
this
for
multiple
is
it
used
two
the
can
with
contained
file
and
of
has
lines
five
word
```

Can anybody tell me, why the set is not sorted in it's natural order(for Strings lexiographic)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: A set isn't sorted. You need to use a `SortedSet` for that.

Comment: Instead of `.map(line -> line.split("[ .,;?!.:()]")) .flatMap(Arrays::stream)`, you can use `.map(Pattern.compile("[ .,;?!.:()]"))::splitAsStream)`. So you are compiling the pattern only once instead of once per line and avoid the creation of an intermediate array for each line…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the ordering is case sensitive, you should map to lower case before sorting.

Besides that, you should collect the output into an ordered collection such as a `List` or some `SortedSet` implementation (though if you use a `SortedSet` there's no need to execute `sorted()`, since the `Set` will be sorted anyway).

A `List` output :

```
List<String> wordSet = stream
            .map(line -> line.split("[ .,;?!.:()]"))
            .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
            .map(String::toLowerCase)
            .sorted()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

EDIT:

As commented by Hank, if you want to eliminate duplicates in the output `Collection`, a `List` won't do, so you'll have to collect the elements into a `SortedSet` implementation.

A `SortedSet` output :

```
Set<String> wordSet = stream
            .map(line -> line.split("[ .,;?!.:()]"))
            .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
            .map(String::toLowerCase)
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));
```

Comment: thank you i solved it now in this way and i perfectly works: SortedSet<String> wordSet;
  Stream<String> stream = java.nio.file.Files.lines(java.nio.file.Paths.get(fileName));
  wordSet = stream
     .map(line -> line.split("[ .,;?!.:()]"))
     .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
     .map(String::toLowerCase)
     .collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));

Comment: `TreeSet` uses a heap sorting algorithm. If you want to use the algorithm from the `Stream` instead, use `.sorted()` and a `LinkedHashSet` (which is ordered but not sorted)

Comment: This solution allows duplicates, which wasn't precluded in the problem, but was implied, I think.

Comment: @HankD That's a good point. I edited the answer to handle it.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a sorted collection like a `TreeSet` using `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER` as a `Comparator`

```
Set<String> set = stream
            .map(line -> line.split("[ .,;?!.:()]"))
            .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(()-> new TreeSet<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)));
```

Or you can sort the elements using a case insensitive comparator and collect it into a collection that maintains insertion order.

```
List<String> list = stream
            .map(line -> line.split("[ .,;?!.:()]"))
            .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
            .sorted(String::compareToIgnoreCase)
            .distinct()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: In the second example you could add a `distinct()` to remove duplicates from the list.

Comment: Note that the comparator you use with the `TreeSet` (`String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`) also works with `.sorted(…)` on a `Stream`. There is no requirement to switch to the method reference `String::compareToIgnoreCase` when operating with streams…

Comment: @Holger sure, I wanted to show different ways, maybe the OP or future visitors avoid toLowerCase for such a task :)